# Kotlin not able to get type interference required Array<Uri>! found Array<Uri?>

Tags: java, android, performance, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am trying to use a `uriArray` for parsing path of images but stuck at one point in kotlin, it's giving me issue of required **Array!** found **Array**

```
 val uriArray = arrayOfNulls<Uri>(imageList.size)
                    for (i in imageList.indices) {
                        val imgaesModel = imageList.get(i)
                        uriArray[i] = Uri.parse("file:" + imgaesModel.getPath())
                    }
                    mFilePathCallback!!.onReceiveValue(uriArray)
           // Above line is giving error
```

Please give me some suggestions as I am new to `Kotlin`, little will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to tasoluko's answer is

```
val uriArray = Array<Uri>(imageList.size) { i ->
    val imagesModel = imageList[i] // get method can be written as indexing
    Uri.parse("file:" + imagesModel.path) // instead of getPath()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `arrayOfNulls`, your `uriArray` consists Uri? (nullable Uri) elements. Because of that onReceiveValue can not receive expected type which is an array of Uri, instead, it receives an array of Uri?. What I suggest is instead of creating an `arrayOfNulls`, use map function in `kotlin` to convert imageList into a `Uri` list, and then convert that list to an array and use it.

It should be something like this I think.

```
val uriList = imagesList.map {
    Uri.parse("file:" + it.getPath())
}
val uriArray = uriList.toTypedArray() // something like this just convert list to array :)
mFilePathCallback!!.onReceiveValue(uriArray)
```

Comment: Your answer will create array of size one containing the entire list, you want `arrayOf(*uriList)` instead (see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs)